# Audience Manager: How to save Contacts in multiple address books?

Tags: 2013, audience-manager

First of all I'd like to know if it's possible to have the same contact (i.e. same name and email details) added into multiple address books across multiple publications?

If so, would you be able to give me some advice or point me in a direction where I could achieve this programmatically?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Contact can only ever exist in one static Address Book. The identification fields you have configured will determine the unique identifier for that Contact and thus determine what is considered a 'duplicate'.

However, Contacts can show up in multiple Dynamic Address Books and they in turn can be assigned to multiple Publications.

So it depends on what you are looking for:

- If you want your visitor to have the same account on multiple sites (i.e. changes on one site also takes effect on the other sites), you could store the Contact in a single static Address Book and use Dynamic Address Books to share them across different Publications. You would then synchronize the static Address Book to a shared database across all of the sites.
- If you want your visitors to be able to sign up with the same details on different sites, but have the accounts be completely separate, you could store the Contacts in separate Address Books per site, synchronize them to separate databases per site, and ensure that you have multiple identification fields -- one of which is unique to the site. This is what the default fields and sample pages do: the unique identifier for a Contact is a combination of an e-mail address and an identifier for the site.
- You can mix and match the above approaches to suit your needs.

As for how to do this programmatically, the static Address Book that the Contact is created in should be specified in the **AddressBookId** property of the Contact object when creating it on the website.

Comment: I'll have a look at mix and matching the approaches you've suggested and get back to you on how it went. Thanks!

Comment: In the end we've decided with simply using the same email address in multiple publication by modifying the import source of each contact (i.e. Example-<PublicationId>). Thanks for your suggestions though!

Comment: Also a perfectly valid approach! That's the deal with these kinds of questions: the answer totally depends on what you need and what makes the most sense to you as an organization.

Answer (score 2):

My Audience Manager knowledge is *rusty* at best... but I seem to remember that the unique identifiers (by default) are the user's email and something we call "WebSiteId" - this means you'd be able to register the same user twice, as long as it was for 2 different WebSiteIds - for instance someuser@somedomain.com / somewebsite.com and someuser@somedomain.com / somewebsite.co.uk - effectively the same email, but on 2 different sites (and therefore 2 different address books).

Using the same website ID and email would fail, since it would be considered a duplicate entry.

Hope this helps... and perhaps someone with more up-to-date AM implementation knowledge can step in.